# How to declare complex dependencies with airflow

Tags: airflow

I'd like to declare dependencies this way, but it doesn't work

```
start >> [a, b >> [b1, b2], c] >> end
```

It raises this error

```
log: Relationships can only be set between Operators; received list
```

How can we achieve that ?

Comment: If I understood what you tried to do, wouldn't `start >> [a,b] >> [b1, b2, c] >> end` do the same as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [TaskGroup](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/task-groups):

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="test",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 30),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
)

with dag:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id="start")
    end = DummyOperator(task_id="end")

    with TaskGroup("task_group") as task_group:
        a = DummyOperator(task_id="a")
        b = DummyOperator(task_id="b")
        b1 = DummyOperator(task_id="b1")
        b2 = DummyOperator(task_id="b2")
        c = DummyOperator(task_id="c")

        b >> [b1, b2]


    start >> task_group >> end
```

[image]

Comment: any idea with Airflow 1 ?

Comment: The most straightforward way would be using [chain()](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d3b066931191b82880d216af103517ea941c74ba/airflow/utils/helpers.py#L154):
```chain(start, [a, c], end)```
```chain(start, b, [b1, b2], end)```
Otherwise you'll unfortunately only be able to use the classic bitshift or `set_downstream`/`set_upstream` style.